# Device Motion Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer

I'm doing an application, which will use as a resource the `accelerometer`. I programmed it in HTML5 and JavaScript, and then I tested the application and it gave different values on different smartphones!

How do I fix this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
var watchID = null;

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

// Start watching the acceleration
//
function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 3 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 3000 };

    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// Stop watching the acceleration
//
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
//
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration
//
function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of these “different values” that you encounter on different smartphones? Which smartphones did you test?

Comment: I tested it on Samsung Galaxy S IV and Sony Xperia E.

The values in Sony Xperia E is
X: 0
Y:0,07~0,15 (unstable)
Z:2,45


The value in Galaxy S IV
X:-0,53
Y:0,05~0,09(unstable)
Z:9.46

the smartphone is resting on a flat table
I have a teacher who also tested in Ios, and gave him different values, but I don’t know which he used.