# Accelerometer problems

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer, intel-xdk, gravity

I'm doing an application, which will use as a resource the accelerometer. I programmed it in HTML5 and JavaScript, and then I tested the application and it gave different values on different smartphones.

I have tested in Samsung Galaxy IV an Sony Xperia E. Both Smartphone's are tested at the same time in flat table.

**The values of Sony Xperia E are:**
**X:**0
**Z:**0,07~0,15 (unstable)
**Z:**2,45

**The values of Samsung Galaxy IV are:**
**X:**-0,53
**Y:**0,05~0,09 (unstable)
**Z:**9,46

I have a teacher who told me that the problem is gravity.

How can fix this? How?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// The watch id references the current `watchAcceleration`
var watchID = null;

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    startWatch();
}

// Start watching the acceleration
//
function startWatch() {

    // Update acceleration every 3 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 300 };

    watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// Stop watching the acceleration
//
function stopWatch() {
    if (watchID) {
        navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
//
function onSuccess(acceleration) {
    var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
    element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x         + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y         + '<br />' +
                        'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z         + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
}

// onError: Failed to get the acceleration
//
function onError() {
    alert('onError!');
}

</script>
 <div id="accelerometer">Waiting for accelerometer...</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Device Motion Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156008/device-motion-plugin)

Comment: I don't think gravity is a problem.  The slight fluctuations you're seeing aren't that unusual, they're very small and this is floating point data.  It looks like the Samsung is giving roughly correct results.  If the experia gives you consistent results (always measures gravity as 2.45, other directions scaled the same way) then you could hack it for that model.  Can you double check using the "Hello Cordova" sample app?  It includes Accelerometer readings also.  It would be helpful to see if it's consistent with your app.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide I saw various kinds of programming and this was the only one that worked! I've walked the search of the "Hello Cordova" sample app. But found .. can you give me a link please!

Comment: Certainly.  It's on github here - https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova but it should be available as a sample also.  When you start a new project, select "Samples and Demos"->"General" then select the "HTML5 + Cordova" tab and it should be the second sample there.

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide thank you! I did not know existed in this intel XDK

Comment: The values are the same. @OldGeeksGuide

Comment: It may be a problem with the phone then.  I found one reference to a similar problem - http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/help/calibrate-accelerometer-gyroscope-t2968665.  They suggested a factory reset, but I don't know why that would make a difference.  Does it affect the x and y axes too?  I.e. if you hold the phone so the edge or side is down, does  it give correct numbers for gravity?  On more thing, if you hold it upside down, i.e. above your head with the screen facing down, is it still around 2.something instead of 9.something?

Comment: the values are those in question!
my teacher said it was the gravity! and that there must be some formula that turns it on generic values. I was asking 'cause I can not find anything on the Net! @OldGeeksGuide